# Is there a free remote desktop program with serial port forwarding for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a free alternative to Windows built-in remote desktop client `mstsc.exe` that supports serial port forwarding.

Comment: What features do you need in addition to serial port forwarding?

Comment: Just the basic features to control a computer remotely, with serial port forwarding.